# Can JMeter HTTP Cookie Manager work with Max-Age value

Tags: jmeter

I have JMeter test where after one request in response headers is set cookie with Max-Age property.

In following requests I am sending cookie in request body.

After Max-Age time pass I expect that jmeter stops sending cookie in request body. But it stil sends cookie.

I am using HTTP Cookie Manager with Cookie policy: standard-strict

Am I using HTTP Cookie Manager right?

How Cookie Manager handles Max-Age parameter in set-cookie in response header?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Cookie Manager doesn't send anything in the request body, it automatically parses incoming cookies and generates appropriate [Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie)

Looking into [JMeter source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/HC4CookieHandler.java#L83) `STANDARD_STRICT` policy stands for RFC6265CookieSpecProvider with `STRICT` compatibility level

In its turn RFC6265CookieSpecProvider in `STRICT` mode [invokes BasicMaxAgeHandler](https://github.com/mydevotion/httpclient/blob/master/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/RFC6265CookieSpecProvider.java#L87)

So given you have `HttpClient4` implementation of your HTTP Request sampler(s) (or even better in [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)) the Max-Age check functionality should work  (unless there is a bug in the HTTPClient itself)

[image]

Comment: Does't work for me

I have response with header
Set-Cookie: sticky_fo=http://{{IP ADDRESS}}; Max-Age=300; Path=/frontoffice/; HttpOnly

and after 5 minutes I am still sending requests with header

sticky_fo=http://{{IP ADDRESS}}

I set HttpClient4 in all reguests

Answer (score 0):

I listed all cookies with preprocessor and cookie has set expires property to 12:43:12 and current time is 12:45:35 (current time is in milliseconds) ... so it seems that cookie with expires property does not work

PreProcessor: Cookie n° 2: sticky_fo: http://10.64.128.238:30701 expires: 1611146592 Current time: 1611146735233